# Angular 2 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm developing a very simple Angular 2 application with only one component, one service and one interface but I came across this error and after a few hours of investigating I still can't find an answer.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.desc.get [as ontimeout] (zone.js:1265)
    at XHRLocalObject.AbstractXHRObject._cleanup (abstract-xhr.js:149)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (abstract-xhr.js:125)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1230)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

I can't really understand why the error is keeps appearing, the application is still functional after the mistake appears but it's frustrating.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a relatively fresh [issue of zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/746), which has already been fixed.

Comment: As a matter of fact, your code is not relevant here (none of it is shown in error's stack), so you can drop it. But you should have started with opening an issue on zone.js instead - or looking for already opened ones. )

Comment: @raina77ow, yes it seems to be fixed in [issue #747](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/747) but is not yet released

Comment: What about applying the patch manually? Yes, it might be quite awkward, but it seems to be a better solution then just downgrading to 0.8.5.

Comment: I would, but even downgrading doesn't quite solve it so I must be doing something wrong. Since it doesn't brake anything, I'm just gonna let this error slide and wait for the patch. Thank you for providing the link to the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem and I solve this downgrading to zone.js@0.8.5 and the problem disappeared. Run the following command in your project folder:

```
npm install zone.js@0.8.5 --save
```

Comment: I cannot get zone.js 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7 or 0.8.8 to work with a simple Angular-cli generated app that uses Angular 4.0.3.

zone.js:1265 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.desc.get [as ontimeout] (zone.js:1265)
    at XHRLocalObject.AbstractXHRObject._cleanup (abstract-xhr.js:149)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (abstract-xhr.js:125)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1230)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)

Answer (score 2):

for now you could do something like:

```
rimraf node_modules
npm cache clear
npm i zone.js@0.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help others, but in my case it was because i was adding a mouseover listener and the function of the mouseover event wasn't defined. Took me a while to find out

```
 b.addListener("mouseover",this.onMouseOver); //this.onMouseOver wasn't defined
```