# how to correct this error in Angular2 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular

How to correct this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" appearing in console of my Angular2 App

Comment: Please provide a code example. More than likely this error is caused from your code, not angular.

Comment: Where is your code sir? Can I see that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556422/angular-2-typeerror-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined)

Comment: Sounds like zoneJS, give downgrading a shot

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to apply on variable which you haven't initialised.