# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined Angular 5 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 5 app that works without problems when I run it in test mode, that is, when I run the application locally using the `ng serve` command. However, when I deploy the application in production mode, that is, through the command `ng build --prod`, the application exports without problems, but when I use the application in a productive environment, this problem appears: (these are images from the browsers console from google and safari)

**Google Chrome Console:**

[image]

**Safari Console:**

[image]

Next I am going to show the component involved in the commented error:

**user-online-quote.component.html**

```
<app-navbar [loggedIn]=loggedIn></app-navbar>
<app-dynamic-form [answers$]="answers$"></app-dynamic-form>
```

**user-online-quote.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicFormService } from '../_services/dynamic-form.service';
import { RadioQuestion }  from '../shared/_shared/answer-radio';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-online-quote',
  templateUrl: './user-online-quote.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-online-quote.component.css'],
  providers:  [DynamicFormService]
})
export class UserOnlineQuoteComponent implements OnInit {
  totalPage:number;
  actualPage:number;
  percentageCompletion:number;
  currentQuestion:string;
  selectedOption:string;
  imageSource:string;
  loggedIn:boolean;
  formId:string;
  //public answers: any[];

  //Signo $ porque es un observable
  public answers$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private service: DynamicFormService, private authService: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn=this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.formId=params['form'];
      this.answers$=this.service.getAnswers(this.formId);
    });
    //this.answers=this.service.getAnswers("CAR00PR");
    this.totalPage=4;
    this.actualPage=1;
    this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
    this.currentQuestion="¿Pregunta de prueba?";
  }

  calculateAdvancePercentage(){
    this.percentageCompletion=(this.actualPage/this.totalPage)*100;
  }

  next(){
    this.actualPage=(this.actualPage+1);
    this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
  }

  back(){
    this.actualPage=(this.actualPage-1);
    this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
  }

}
```

**dinamic-form.component.html**

```
<div class="space"></div>
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '0px', fullScreenBackdrop:true }"></ngx-loading>
<div *ngIf="submitted===false" class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="mx-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div>
      <p>{{currentQuestion.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width]="percentageCompletion + '%'" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
      <hr> 
      <div>
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <div *ngFor="let answer of answers$ | async">
            <div [ngSwitch]="answer.controlType">
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
                <div class="radios checkbox-group">
                  <div [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="col-lg-12">
                    <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" [id]="answer.id" type="radio" [value]="answer.label" (click)="next(null,answer.child)">
                      <label [for]="answer.id" class="button-label">
                        {{answer.label}}  
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio_textbox'">
                <div class="radios checkbox-group">
                  <div [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="col-lg-12">
                    <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" [id]="answer.id" type="radio" (click)="showTextbox ? showTextbox = false : showTextbox = true;">
                      <label [for]="answer.id" class="button-label">
                        {{answer.label}}  
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-12">
                    <input [hidden]="!showTextbox" type="text" class="form-control" [placeholder]="answer.placeholder" [formControlName]="answer.controlName" [id]="answer.id">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button [hidden]="!showTextbox" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" (click)="next(null,answer.child)">Siguiente</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'file'">
                <div [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label [for]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</label>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" type="file" class="custom-file-input" [id]="answer.id" lang="es" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">{{fileName}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="answer.required===true">
                          <small *ngIf="form.get(answer.controlName).status=='INVALID'" class="form-text text-muted-error">Debes tener una imagen de referencia para poder continuar</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="my-4"></div>
                </div>
              </div>    
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'file_next'">
                <div [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label [for]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</label>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" type="file" class="custom-file-input" [id]="answer.id" lang="es" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">{{fileName}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="answer.required===true">
                          <small *ngIf="form.get(answer.controlName).status=='INVALID'" class="form-text text-muted-error">Debes tener una imagen de referencia para poder continuar</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-4"></div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <button
                        (click)='next(answer.validations,answer.next)'
                        class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                        Siguiente
                      </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)" class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label [for]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</label>
                <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" type="text" class="form-control" [id]="answer.id" [placeholder]="answer.placeholder">
                <div *ngIf="answer.required===true">
                  <small *ngIf="form.get(answer.controlName).status=='INVALID'" class="form-text text-muted-error">Este campo es obligatorio</small>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox_next'" [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label [for]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</label>
                  <input [formControlName]="answer.controlName" type="text" class="form-control" [id]="answer.id" [placeholder]="answer.placeholder">
                  <div *ngIf="answer.required===true">
                    <small *ngIf="form.get(answer.controlName).status=='INVALID'" class="form-text text-muted-error">Este campo es obligatorio</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="my-4"></div>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button
                    (click)='next(answer.validations,answer.next)'
                    class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    Siguiente
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12" [hidden]="!(currentQuestion.id===answer.parent)">
                  <label for="description">{{answer.label}}</label>
                  <textarea [formControlName]="answer.controlName" class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="my-4"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>

      <div class="my-4"></div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button 
          (click)='back()' 
          class="btn btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Atrás
        </button>
        <button 
          [hidden]="currentQuestion.last==true"
          (click)='cancel()' 
          class="btn btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Cancelar
        </button>
        <button 
          [hidden]="currentQuestion.last==false"
          [disabled]="form.invalid"
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-outline-success"
          (click)="onSubmit()">
            Enviar Solicitud
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="mx-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="submitted==true" class="container">
  <div class="space">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-10 justify">
                <p>Tu solicitud se ha enviado correctamente, debes esperar un máximo de 2 días para que el experto elabore una cotización
                  de acuerdo a tus requerimientos. 
                </p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard_usuario/negociaciones/en_proceso']">Ver negociación</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**dinamic-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup }                 from '@angular/forms';
import { AnswerBase }              from '../shared/_shared/answer-base';
import { AnswerControlService }    from '../_services/answer-control.service';
import { DynamicFormService } from '../_services/dynamic-form.service';
import { Question } from '../_models/question';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx"
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { QuoteDto } from "../_dtos/quoteDto";
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.css'],
  providers: [ AnswerControlService ]
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() answers$: Observable<AnswerBase<any>[]>;
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';
  questionsList : Map<string, Question>;
  totalPage:number;
  actualPage:number;
  percentageCompletion:number;
  currentQuestion:Question;
  previousQuestion:Question;
  backwardQuestions:Array<string>;
  loading:boolean;
  fileName:string;
  photo:File;
  image:any;
  nextDisable:boolean;
  userId:string;
  providerId:string;
  formId:string;
  submitted:boolean;


  constructor(private qcs: AnswerControlService, 
    private dynamicFormervice: DynamicFormService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private location:Location,
    private router:Router) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading=true;
    this.submitted=false;
    this.fileName="Seleccionar un archivo";
    this.nextDisable=true;
    this.backwardQuestions= new Array();
    this.currentQuestion=new Question('','',false);
    this.form= new FormGroup({});
    this.questionsList= new Map<string, Question>();
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.userId=params['user'];
      this.providerId=params['provider'];
      this.formId=params['form'];
        this.dynamicFormervice.getTotalPages(this.formId).subscribe(total => {
          this.totalPage=total;
          this.actualPage=1;
          this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
            this.dynamicFormervice.getQuestions(this.formId).subscribe(items =>{
              items.map(item =>{
                this.questionsList.set(item.id,item);
              });
            this.dynamicFormervice.getInitialQuestionId(this.formId).subscribe(id =>{
              this.currentQuestion=this.questionsList.get(id);
              this.previousQuestion=this.currentQuestion;
              this.loading=false;
            });
          });
        });
    });
    this.answers$.subscribe(a=>{
      this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(a);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.loading=true;
    this.payLoad=JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
    let quote:QuoteDto = new QuoteDto();
    quote.requirements= this.payLoad;
    this.dynamicFormervice.createQuote(quote,this.userId,this.providerId).subscribe((resp:HttpResponse<String>)=>{
      this.dynamicFormervice.uploadQuotationImage(this.photo,resp.body.substring(resp.body.indexOf(':')+1,resp.body.lastIndexOf('"'))).
      subscribe(resp => {
        this.submitted=true;
        this.loading=false;
      });
    });
  }

  calculateAdvancePercentage(){
    this.percentageCompletion=(this.actualPage/this.totalPage)*100;
  }

  next(validatios:string, childId:string){
    if(validatios!=null){
      let controlRestrictions:string[]=validatios.split(',');
      let validCount=0;
      for (let cr of controlRestrictions) {
        if(this.form.get(cr).status=='VALID'){
          validCount++;
        }
     }
     if(validCount==controlRestrictions.length){
       this.nextDisable=false;
       this.backwardQuestions.push(this.currentQuestion.id);
       this.currentQuestion=this.questionsList.get(childId);
       if(this.currentQuestion.last==true){
        this.percentageCompletion=100;
       }else{
        this.actualPage=(this.actualPage+1);
        this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
       }
     }
    }else{
      this.backwardQuestions.push(this.currentQuestion.id);
      this.currentQuestion=this.questionsList.get(childId);
      if(this.currentQuestion.last==true){
        this.percentageCompletion=100;
      }else{
       this.actualPage=(this.actualPage+1);
       this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
      }
    }
  }

  back(){
    if(this.actualPage==1){
      this.location.back();
    }
    else{
      let questionId:string = this.backwardQuestions.pop();
      this.currentQuestion=this.questionsList.get(questionId);
      this.actualPage=(this.actualPage-1);
      this.calculateAdvancePercentage();
    }
  }

  cancel(){
    this.navegateToProfessionForm();
  }

  navegateToProfessionForm(){
    switch (this.formId) {
      case 'ALB00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '1' } });
        break;
      case 'CAR00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '2' } });
        break;
      case 'DIS00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '3' } });
        break;
      case 'ELE00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '4' } });
        break;  
      case 'CLI00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '5' } });
        break;
      case 'FUM00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '6' } });
        break;
      case 'MAQ00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '7' } });
        break;
      case 'PIN00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '8' } });
        break;
      case 'PLO00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '9' } });
        break;
      case 'JAR00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '10' } });
        break;
      case 'SOL00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '11' } });
        break;
      case 'TAP00PR':
        this.router.navigate(['/expertos'], { queryParams: { profession: '12' } });
        break;
      default:
  }
  }

  onFileChange(event) {
    this.loading=true;
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    let image:File = event.target.files[0];
    let reader=new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
      reader.onload = (event:any) => {
        let base64=event.target.result
        let filename=image.name;
        let type=image.type;
        this.reduceQuality(base64,filename,type,(file)=>{
          this.photo = file;
          this.fileName=this.photo.name;
          this.loading=false;
        });
      }
    }
    else{
      this.loading=false;
    }
  }

  getBase64(file,callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
      let result = reader.result;
      callback(result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
 }

  reduceQuality(base64Image,filename,extension,callback){
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
   image.onload = ()=>{
    var width = image.width,
            height = image.height,
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
        canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;

        // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    let url:string = '';
    if(extension=='image/jpeg'){
      url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.1);
    }
    else{
      url = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    let file:File=this.dataURLtoFile(url,filename);
    callback(file);
  };
    image.src = base64Image;  
  }
  dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    let arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.12.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.3",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "offcanvas-bootstrap": "^2.5.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

The question is why this error only appears after having exported the application (when it finishes the process it does not show any kind of error or warning). Why is this so strange? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show more code, specifically where the ‘apply’ is accessed.

Comment: @MichaelD I added more code, but the problem lies when the app is exported

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your code is not compatible with AOT. Try to build your app with `ng build --prod --aot false` to see if it works, (or `ng serve --aot` to see if you have this error).

Comment: I'm used "ng build --prod --aot false" and finally works!. But I am concerned that you may not be able to take advantage of AOT. Any ideas how I could solve the problem?

Comment: It's not an easy task. When I was working in a similar situation, it took me hours to do it in an existing code. All information you need can be found in Angular site: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler , but you need to find where to change it.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an application using in production mode (`ng bull --prod`), it will check every single mistake which you have done in the code. In order to prevent this issue, you can follow one of these two steps.

1. When you define the object which contains the 'apply' property, you can initialize it with some value (according to the variable type)
2. You can check that 'apply' property is `undefined` or `null`, before using it in the code.

the first point might resolve your problem if it happen in the compile time. If the issue happen in the runtime you need to follow the 2nd point.

Comment: When it finishes the process it does not show any kind of error or warning

Comment: when you build in production mode you get the error, right? Or is this happen only in the runtime?

Comment: This happen only in the runtime

Comment: So you need to follow the 2nd point which I have mentioned and check the variable is nullable or undefined before use it.

Comment: If that were the case it would be reflected in the testing environment. Here something else happens.

Comment: Do you know the place where you have use the apply property?

Comment: No. I don't recognize that property

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560117/7096559